# Does Go run defer function after called C function that longjmp to somewhere?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm stuck in this question.

A go function like this:

```
func GoFunction(str string) {
    cstr := C.CString(str)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))
    C.CFunction(cstr)
}
```

And `C.CFunction()` use `longjmp` to jump to somewhere.

My question is that if `C.CFunction()` `longjmp`, does defer function run? Does `cstr` be freed?

Comment: defer function runs even if your program exits abnormally, so yes.

Comment: @nilsocket Not _always_: https://play.golang.org/p/uxxpN6HZYed

Comment: @EmilePels you were explicitly mentioning to exit the program with `os.Exit()` , once this function is executed it exits, if user didn't mention to exit but due to some err or program panic then defer does run.

Comment: @nilsocket This rests on some ambiguous definitions. If we define an "abnormal exit" as one in which `os.Exit` is called (rather than control flow naturally reaching the end of the `main` function), then Emile is correct. The point being made, which is an important one, is that there are conditions in Go in which deferred calls may *not* be run, and it is important to represent this possibility for completeness whenever exit conditions are discussed.